# "new project" and "new file" don't work

Tags: netbeans

I have been using netbeans Java for a number of years.  Recently my laptop gave up the ghost so I bought a new one, then went on line to download a new copy of netbeans to the new computer.  It appeared to have worked- the little blue cube icon appeared on my computer screen and when I clicked on it I got the usual screen for netbeans.  But when I clicked on "new project" or "new file", nothing at all happened.

Comment: Which version of NetBeans and which version of Java are you using? Note that NetBeans 8.x only supports a JDK <= 8. For JDK 9 and greater use [NetBeans 9](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html).

Comment: Thanks.  After deleting and reloading Java and NetBeans SEVERAL times (in one of which the 'splash screen' came up and, after a few seconds, disappeared with nothing else happening!) I finally have everything running again.  But I still have no idea why or what happened.

Comment: It's good that you have things working. One possible cause of the symptom you describe (_"the 'splash screen' came up and, after a few seconds, disappeared with nothing else happening"_) is when NetBeans is trying to access Java though an invalid path. That can happen if you [1] Install Java version 'x'. [2] Install NetBeans [3] Remove Java version 'x', replacing it with Java version  'y'. [4] NetBeans won't start.    To fix that (in case you ever hit the problem again) you need to set a valid value for the property **netbeans_jdkhome** in file **netbeans.conf**.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue with netbeans 8.2 and jdk > 8u241 version.
So I point to jdk1.8 home path into netbeans jdkhome. Get positive result.